# Codeigniter & disallowed key characters issue with my htaccess

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have setup an htaccess rule (see below)

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

My intention is that any of the following links will be redirected to site.com the problem is the question mark character (?) as this causes an 'Disallowed key characters' error in Codeigniter framework. I could modify the permitted characters in the config file but this is not recommended for security purposes.

The links I aim to redirect looks like the following..

```
http://www.site.com/images/flash/main.swf?config=/flash/flash_output/133/location.htm
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround that doesn't involve [changing the permitted characters in the config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9413223/367456), or is this the only workable option?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with allowing '?' in

Comment: even though `?` isn't listed in the allowed characters codeigniter doesn't restrict that in the url.  Unless you've changed something somewhere my installation allows this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend URL-escaping your "config" parameter.  It might be getting confused which file to access (in which case, the "?" character is in an unexpected place).  Beyond that, it's good practice.

http://www.site.com/images/flash/main.swf?config=%2Fflash%2Fflash_output%2F133%2Flocation.htm%0A

Answer (score 0):

You might be used white space while naming your textbox.

Incorrect way to produce such error:

> input type="text" id="test_text" name="**test    _text**"

Correct Way:

> input type="text" id="test_text" name="**test_text**"