# Security concerns with permitted uri characters in Codeigniter

Tags: security, codeigniter

I've had to change the $config['permitted_uri_chars'] to the following :-

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\?=';
```

What are the security implications of adding the ? and = characters to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `$this->input->post()` then even if somebody passes a parameter in the url its not going to matter.